# What should the google map api key be?

Tags: google-maps

If I have this URL

http://domain.com/test3/eu/flickr-map/

What url do I use to generate the api key.  I have put my code into production and what ever I do I can't seem to get an API key to work.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use "http://domain.com" as my URL when generating the key.  That way you can use it within other folders on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [FAQ entry](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem) about the key and domains?

You may need to sign up for a new key if you've effectively changed URL.

Answer (score 0):

Sign up at [this address](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html) to get a key for a specific domain then use that key when calling the Google JS files.

Example: Say I entered a domain at the address above and got a key of:

> ABQIAAAAohKw8F5hsRCukQas4PbQXxS6jl7DzHm5BhVW2hKJ3KnZdh5-DxTaQN7mL8OMRAQtuGL6z2B0_Ql19Q

I would then use that key in my calls like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAohKw8F5hsRCukQas4PbQXxS6jl7DzHm5BhVW2hKJ3KnZdh5-DxTaQN7mL8OMRAQtuGL6z2B0_Ql19Q" type="text/javascript"></script>
```